# Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty} P(Y \geq y)\ dy = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(Y \gt y)\ dy.$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $Y$ be a non-negative random variable in a probability measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P).$ Then it is well known that $$\mathrm E[Y] = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb P (Y \geq y)\ dy.$$

Can we conclude that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb P (Y \geq y)\ dy = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb P (Y \gt y)\ dy.$$ For that we need to show that $$\mu \left (\left \{y \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}\ \big |\ \mathbb P (Y = y) \gt 0 \right \} \right ) = 0$$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R.$ If $Y$ takes only countably many values i.e. if $Y$ is a discrete random variable or if $Y$ is a continuous random variable having a density function then this is clearly true. But is it true for arbitrary random variables?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$P(Y=y)$ can be $>\frac 1  k$ for at most $k$ values of $y$ since the sum of all those probabilites cannot exceed $1$. Taking union over $k$ we see that $P(Y=y)>0$ for at most countably many values of $y$. Since countable sets have Lebesgue measure $0$ the stated equality follows.

Comment: Very nice argument. +1